# Table repeats 12 times because of 12 strings in fire base

Tags: javascript, cordova, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When retrieving the fire base data the html table repeats its self 12 tables, 
this is because there are 12 strings.

I have added pictures below showing the json list and my code and what happens.

[Json File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VEbjm.png)

[Table Repeating](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCm3v.png)

[Data Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5LEF.png)

database.ref().child(dv).once('value', function(snapshot){

```
    if(snapshot.exists()){

        var content = '';

        snapshot.forEach(function(data){

            var val = snapshot.val();

            content +='<tr>';

            content += '<tr class="prytimrh"> <th rowspan="8" bgcolor="#4da6ff">' + val.d_date + '</th> <th> Prayer </th>   <th> Start </th> <th> Jammat </th> </tr>';

            content += '<tr class="prytimr1"> <th>Fajr:</th> <td>' + val.fajr_begins + '</td>'; content               += '<td>' + val.fajr_jamah + '</td> </tr>';

            content += '<tr class="prytimr2"> <th>Sunrise:</th> <td>'           + val.sunrise + '</td>'; content                 += '<td>' + val.sunrise + '</td> </tr>';

            content += '<tr class="prytimr1"> <th>Zuhur:</th> <td>'              + val.zuhr_begins + '</td>'; content                    += '<td>' + val.zuhr_jamah + '</td> </tr>';

            content += '<tr class="prytimr2"> <th>Asr:</th> <td>'           + val.asr_mithl + '</td>'; content                    += '<td>' + val.asr_jamah + '</td> </tr>';

            content += '<tr class="prytimr1"> <th>Margrib</th> <td>'               + val.maghrib_begins + '</td>'; content                      += '<td>' + val.maghrib_jamah+ '</td> </tr>';

            content += '<tr class="prytimr2"> <th>Isha</th> <td>'               + val.isha_begins + '</td>'; content              += '<td>' + val.isha_jamah + '</td> </tr>';

            content += '<tr class="prytimr1"> <th>Jummah</th> <td>'                + val.type_prayer_start + '</td>'; content                    += '<td>' + val.type_prayer_jamah +  '</td> </tr>';

            content += '</tr>';
        });
        $('#djprayer').append(content);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should notice [that](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#listen_for_value_events):

> The listener receives a snapshot that contains the data at the
>   specified location in the database at the time of the event. You can
>   retrieve the data in the snapshot with the val() method.

You should retrieve the data with the val() method first, and loop the `snapshot.val()` instead of `snapshot` object.

```
database.ref().child(dv).once('value', function(snapshot){

    if(snapshot.exists()){

        var models = snapshot.val();

        var content = '';

        models.forEach(function (model) {

            var val = model;

            content +='<tr>';

            content += '<tr class="prytimrh"> <th rowspan="8" bgcolor="#4da6ff">' + val.d_date + '</th> <th> Prayer </th>   <th> Start </th> <th> Jammat </th> </tr>';

            content += '<tr class="prytimr1"> <th>Fajr:</th> <td>' + val.fajr_begins + '</td>'; content               += '<td>' + val.fajr_jamah + '</td> </tr>';

            content += '<tr class="prytimr2"> <th>Sunrise:</th> <td>'           + val.sunrise + '</td>'; content                 += '<td>' + val.sunrise + '</td> </tr>';

            content += '<tr class="prytimr1"> <th>Zuhur:</th> <td>'              + val.zuhr_begins + '</td>'; content                    += '<td>' + val.zuhr_jamah + '</td> </tr>';

            content += '<tr class="prytimr2"> <th>Asr:</th> <td>'           + val.asr_mithl + '</td>'; content                    += '<td>' + val.asr_jamah + '</td> </tr>';

            content += '<tr class="prytimr1"> <th>Margrib</th> <td>'               + val.maghrib_begins + '</td>'; content                      += '<td>' + val.maghrib_jamah+ '</td> </tr>';

            content += '<tr class="prytimr2"> <th>Isha</th> <td>'               + val.isha_begins + '</td>'; content              += '<td>' + val.isha_jamah + '</td> </tr>';

            content += '<tr class="prytimr1"> <th>Jummah</th> <td>'                + val.type_prayer_start + '</td>'; content                    += '<td>' + val.type_prayer_jamah +  '</td> </tr>';

            content += '</tr>';

        });

        $('#djprayer').append(content);
    }
});
```

Comment: thank you but now i get the error message "Uncaught TypeError: models.forEach is not a function"

Comment: what is `dv` and your database structure? seems you were fetching object, `snapshot.val()` is object and not array

Comment: var currentTime = new Date()
var month = currentTime.getMonth()
var day = currentTime.getDate()
var dv = ('0' + '/' + month + '/' + day)
//........................................

Comment: `forEach` function is available only if it is `list` or `array`. I guess you are saving data for each date, and you want to fetch all the data each month? you should change the dv to `('0' + '/' + month)`

Comment: what about the + '/' + day? the dv is 0/11/17 0 = top 11 = month 17 = child which contains all the data my database is added as a picture in question if that helps.

Comment: you should think about your data structure, change the dv and `typeof snapshot.val()` can help.

Comment: Manged to make it work using : var val = snapshot.child(DATABSE LOCATION).val();